# How to handle javascript link in Android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have a website and it contains a textField with a link

```
<a class="xyz-icon" href="javascript:print()">
```

And I would like to make an Android app which use webview but when I click the field do nothing. It works in browser. 
My Webview config is:

```
    webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    Webview.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    Webview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    Webview.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I have to put js injection in the `onPageFinished` method because every navigation delete the js.

So I made a JS Interface [like this](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)

then in the `onPageFinished` goes smthing like `myWebView.loadUrl(“javascript:(js code)“)`